# Compare date time zone with time() in perl

Tags: perl, date, time, compare, zone

I am trying to compare a file creation time which is in the format: 08-07-2016 08:16:26 GMT with the current time using time() in perl.
Since time() returns epoch time, I am not sure how to find the time difference between these two different time formats.

I tried something like below and for obvious reasons, I get an error saying: "Argument 08-07-2016 08:16:26 GMT" isn't numeric in subtraction".

```
my $current_time = time();
my $time_diff = $creation_time - $current_time;
if ($time_diff > 10) {                  #compare if the difference is greater than 10hours
    # do something...
}
```

Some of the questions I have:

1. Since I want to compare only the hour difference, how can I extract just the hours from both these time formats?
2. I am unsure if the comparison of $time_diff > 10 is right. How to represent 10hours? 10*60?

OR is there a way to at least convert any given time format into epoch using DateTime or Time::Local?

How can I pass a a date parameter to a DateTime constructor?

```
my $dt1 = DateTime-> new (
                 year =>'1998',
                 month =>'4',
                 day   =>'4',
                 hour  =>'21',
                 time_zone =>'local'
                 );
```

Instead can we do something like

```
my $date = '08-07-2016 08:16:26 GMT';
my $dt1 = DateTime->new($date);  # how can i pass a parameter to the constructor
print Dumper($dt1->epoch);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You'll need to convert $current_time into epoch format or into some kind of date-time object. I'd use DateTime::Format::Strptime for that.

Comment: Where did you get the `$creation_time` from? Is it guaranteed to always be a GMT time?

Comment: Thanks ikegami. I will try DateTime::Format.
redneb: $creation_time is the time when my file was created and yes it is always in GMT time.

Comment: How is `$creation_time` populated? Could you change that code to get the value in a more useful format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been a standard part of Perl since 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $creation_string = '08-07-2016 08:16:26 GMT';

my $creation_time = Time::Piece->strptime($creation_string, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z');
my $current_time = gmtime;

my $diff = $current_time - $creation_time;

say $diff; # Difference in seconds
say $diff->pretty;
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, but Time::Piece is not available in our /usr/bin/

Comment: Is there a way to atleast convert any given time format into epoch using DateTime or Time::Local?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect to see Time::Piece in /usr/bin - as a library, it belongs in /usr/lib :-) But if you don't have Time::Piece installed, you either have a really old version of Perl or a Red Hat-style broken installation. You should get that fixed as soon as possible.